# How do the time loops work in Fringe Season 4 episode "And Those We've Left Behind"

Tags: time-travel, fringe

In Fringe season 4 episode "And Those We've Left Behind", there's a man who put his house into the past. He says it only works for 47 minutes at a time. However, his house is 4 years in the past. Did he loop the 47 minutes until he was 4 years back? Otherwise, how was he so far in the past?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The man in the episode has built a device that allows him to move itself and a surrounding area back in time. The device's effect lasts for 47 minutes, during which time everything in the "bubble" is transported back into its own past.

He chose to go back 4 years into his past because that was near the end of his wife's career as a theoretical physicist. (She began showing symptoms of Alzheimer's 3 years prior to the episode.) The time-bubble theory was actually her work; he is an engineer and used her calculations to build a working device from her research. He takes her research with him, and convinces her to keep working on it. Each time she makes progress he brings that material back into the present with her, then takes it back again for her to pick up where she left off.

His goal was to keep going back and giving his wife 47 minute bursts of time to continue work on the theory, until she (hopefully) figured out how to make the effect permanent.

Answer (score 6):

The house is in the past 4 years ago, for 47 minutes at a time.  It is a direct jump to 4 years ago and moves forward, minute for minute until the end of the jump.

[Fridgepedia says it is 47 seven minutes at a time](http://fringepedia.net/wiki/And_Those_We%27ve_Left_Behind)